# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException after rotate device with LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> implementation

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

Exception launched:

- **after** getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(FORECAST_LOADER, null, this)
- **before** onCreateLoader()

. 
What happend??. **Can I use the same used the same LoaderID to LoaderCallbacks??**

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int FORECAST_LOADER = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .................
        // Init Loader data from provider
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(FORECAST_LOADER, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Long routeId = 1234; 

        Uri routesUri = RouteContract.RouteEntry.buildRouteUri(routeId);
        return new CursorLoader(this,
            routesUri,
            RouteContract.RouteEntry.FORECAST_COLUMNS,
            null,
            null,
            null);
     }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        ..............(Run OK)
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        ............. (Run OK)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution:

- **init** activity (savedInstanceState == null): **initLoader**
- After **rotate** device (savedInstanceState != null): **restartLoader**

  ```
  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
      getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(FORECAST_LOADER, null, this);
  } else {
      getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(FORECAST_LOADER, null, this);
  }
  ```